# Windows application wont read all data from serial port

Tags: vb.net, winforms, logging, arduino, serial-port

I've created a Windows Form that I intend on using to pull data from a data logging Arduino. Currently, the Arduino has an SD card mounted on it that has a log file containing the data I want to receive. Using the Arduino IDE serial monitor, I was able to test sending and receiving serial data. The Ardunio sketch waits for an 'r' character and once it receives it, it sends all of the data in the log file to the serial monitor. This has been tested and works 100% of the time within the Arduino IDE. I now have a Windows form GUI to allow for reading the data directly to a log file on the PC without having to remove the SD card (there are reasons why this is necessary). I have no issue connecting to the serial port, and it seems like there is no issue reading data, until I get a little ways into the file.

When outputting the read data to a list box, I noticed it would stop way before the end of the file. Assuming this might be a multi-thread issue, I decided to try directly writing to a file instead of updating the GUI. This also failed and upon inspecting the created log file, I noticed that sometimes, it would have data in it and sometimes it wouldn't. Then instead of trying to read the whole file, I began attempting to read only certain amounts of data. I can read up to about 110 lines of data before the program stops being able to do so consistently. When the program fails and I close it, checking the log file shows that I have 2048 characters in the file, which is the write buffer size of the serial port. Changing this number causes the number of characters to match the buffer size. Attempting to flush data after each write to the file causes the number of characters left in the file to be seemingly random instead of matching the buffer size.

VB Code:

```
Public Class mainForm
    Public Shared logFile As System.IO.StreamWriter
    Public Shadows num As Int16 = 0

    'this is the sub that checks for serial data and is writing the read data to the previously created log file
    Private Sub SerialPort_DataReceived(sender As Object, e As IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles serialPort.DataReceived
        Dim readData As String = serialPort.ReadLine()
        num += 1
        If readData = "EOF" Then
            logFile.Close()
            MsgBox("Done")
        End If
        logFile.Write(readData)
        If num = 110 Then
            MsgBox("Done")
            serialPort.Close()
            logFile.Close()
        End If
    End Sub

    'this sub allows the user to connect to the correct serial port
    'I'm almost positive the problem does not lie here
    Private Sub BtnConnect_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnConnect.Click
        serialPort.Close()
        Dim comPortName As String = "COM" + txtComPort.Text
        serialPort.PortName = comPortName
        Try
            serialPort.Open()
            lstLog.Items.Add("Connected to serial port " + comPortName)
        Catch
            lstLog.Items.Add("Could not connect to serial port " + comPortName)
        End Try
    End Sub

    'this sub creates the log file and sends the 'r' to the Arduino to begin reading the sd card
    Private Sub BtnReadData_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReadData.Click
        logFile = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("C:\Users\AHNEHR\Documents\Docs\test1.txt", True)
        serialPort.WriteLine("r")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Arduino Sketch:

```
#include <SdFat.h>
#include <SPI.h>

const int relayPin = 9;
const int sdChip = 10;
SdFat sd;
SdFile dataLog;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(relayPin,OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    char data = Serial.read();
    if (data == 'r') {
      if (!sd.begin(sdChip)) {
        Serial.println("Failed to Initialize SD Card");
      }
      else Serial.println("SD Card Initialized");
      if (!dataLog.open("log.txt", O_READ)) {         
        Serial.println("Failed to open file.");
      }
      else Serial.println("Opened Log");
      while (dataLog.available()) {
        Serial.write(dataLog.read());
      }
      Serial.println("EOF");
      dataLog.close();
    }
  }
}
```

The "if readData = EOF" is supposed to check for the end of the file, since the Arduino sketch writes this once the entire log file has been output to serial, but I never made it there, so the other if statement checks the number of times a read has been done and stops if it is 110. For numbers less than 100 I have no problem writing all of the data to the log file, but once I get around 100-110, the program begins to malfunction.

The data in the log file on the SD card is formatted like:
04 Aug 2019 06:57 T:ERRC P:ERRpsi
04 Aug 2019 06:58 T:ERRC P:ERRpsi
And I expect the created log file to match the log file on the sd card directly, but instead I get around 80/90 lines that match, and the program stops working and won't continue to write to the log file. I believe the log file on the sd card has about 900 lines total. My vb skills aren't great, so I'm hoping there's something obvious that I'm missing, but I've tried everything I know and don't know why I can only read some of the serial data. Any help figuring out why this happens and how to fix it is greatly appreciated.

*Edit: I have also made sure the baud rates of the Arduino sketch and the serial port match at 115200. Upon some more testing, it definitely seems as though this is a problem with the serial port and not the file.

Comment: You already found the problem. You expect Arduino and Windows to be perfectly sync'ed, while in real world a slight lag or latency on any one side, might have unexpected result, and the probability is cumulative, that's why it always happens after some time. You have to implement a flow control after every line or multiple of lines, to ensure arduino waits for windows to complete and be ready to receive.

Comment: Yes as @AlessandroMandelli points out it seems to be a timing issue. i would only send one line after receiving the 'r' command from the Windows Form. Then when the Windows Form has processed this line it sends a new command 'r'.

Comment: I think in your `SerialPort_DataReceived` event you'll want to use `serialPort.ReadExisting()` instead of `serialPort.ReadLine()`.  There may be more than a single line available to read.  Or a complete line might not be available and the `ReadLine` call will block until a complete line is received.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @B.Letz  I've now edited both the Windows form and the Arduino sketch so now the sketch only sends one line at a time when receiving the 'r' command, and I send the 'r' command after every write on the windows side. This is having the same issue as before. I can repeatedly click the read button and eventually get to the end of the file, but it only works in small chunks of varying size. Should I upload this modified version of the code? And do you have any other ideas as to what might help?

Comment: You are still doing it wrong. You can't read a line unless a line is already there to be read. Because at 115200 one bit is 1e-5 seconds, 1 byte is 1e-4 seconds, you have to wait at least 1ms every 10 bytes, before attempting to read. So as a first try, put a Thread.Sleep(10) before readline.

Comment: @AlessandroMandelli I've put the Thread.Sleep in and I still can't read the whole file in one go. Making the delay longer seems to allow for larger chunks to be read at once, but this is still inconsistent. What else can I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things, I know you are new to `SerialPorts` and you made a good first attempt.  I would recommend the following:

1. The `DataReceived` Event fires somewhat randomly, example it could fire mid string so you might only get the `EO` in one event and the `F` in another event.  To solve this, you need to build a string and rely on a character that lets you know when you have the whole string.  This is generally done with a Carriage Return (`\r`) or a Line Feed (`\n`).
2. As @gunnerone suggested, you should use the `ReadExisting()` function as it returns ALL the data in the Data Received buffer, ReadLine may cause you to miss data.
3. Make sure your baud rates match.  `serialPort.BaudRate = 115200;`

Here is some example code to get you started, sorry it's C# but you should be able to translate to VB.

```
char LF = (char)10;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
string currentLine = string.Empty;

private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string Data = serialPort1.ReadExisting();

    foreach (char c in Data)
    {
        if (c == LF)
        {
            sb.Append(c);

            CurrentLine = sb.ToString();
            sb.Clear();

            //parse CurrentLine here or print it to textbox
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Couple of things to note:

1. LF is the character I'm looking for in this example to let me know I have the whole string.  I'm basically building a string until I see this character then I parse the string or do whatever you need to do.
2. I clear my string I'm building right away, because the `DataReceived` event is multi-threaded so its possible to fire while in it.  So we want to clear it asap so it can start building the next line.

Comment: 2 Questions: I'm assuming CurrentLine is a string variable? And is this meant to be implemented while the Arduino is sending all of the data at once, or with only 1 line sent at a time? It seems as though it's meant for all at once, but I cant get this solution to work in my form.

Comment: *Update: I was not correctly checking for Line Feeds, I forgot VB uses vbLf instead of \n. The Form is now working as intended, but I get a bunch of EOF lines at the end of the listbox that I'm putting the values in. I can't get the if statement to match the EOF string in the serial input to match any string I check for, so the serial port never closes. How can I compare the strings? I've tried checking for "EOF" + vbLf and this does not work

Comment: EOF is not a line, nor a string. It's a byte. Are you sure you're checking against the correct type?

Comment: @AlessandroMandelli In my case, "EOF" _is_ a string that's serially output by the Arduino sketch once it reaches the end of the log file. I just chose to make the string "EOF" because it's something familiar, rather than "END" or "DONE" which also would've worked. The problem I was having was due to the way I was parsing the string and the inclusion of the vbCr and vbLf characters. I have figured out the issue though.

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out.  Yes, `CurrentLine` is just a temporary string variable to put the string builder string into quickly before you do that parsing (parsing can take some time and we want the string builder to start building the next string).For comparing strings I generally go with `.Contains("EOF")`. In your case using the example above, `if(CurrentLine.Contains("EOF")) MsgBox("Done")`